update_plugins_hostname filter show available updates
I am trying to get update_plugins_hostname filter to work to show plugin updates.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_plugins_hostname
I used this sample plugin, however plugin doesnt show updates available (it just show version 1.0 installed). This is the only plugin I have activated. No errors. Updates are shown with other premium pluigns if I activate them.
When is this update_plugins_hostname filter suppose to fire? and how could I test this?
    /*
    Plugin Name: Sample Plugin Name
    Plugin URI: https://mydomain.com
    Description: Your Plugin Description
    Author: Name
    Version: 1.0
    Update URI: https://mydomain.com/simple-wp-plugin-update
    */

    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

    //Run your plugin as usual
    if( ! class_exists( 'SampleExtension' ) ) {
        class SampleExtension {

            public function __construct() {
            
                    //Check for updates
                    require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'class-update.php' );
                    $update = new Simple_Update_Check('simple-wp-plugin-update');                 
                   
            }

        }

        new SampleExtension();
    }

class-update.php:
    defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

    if( ! class_exists( 'Simple_Update_Check' ) ) {
        class Simple_Update_Check{
            public $plugin_slug;
            public $api_url;
            public function __construct($plugin_slug) {
                $this->plugin_slug = $plugin_slug;
                $this->api_url = 'https://mydomain.com/sample.json';
                add_filter('update_plugins_mydomain.com', array($this, 'update'), 10, 4);
                add_filter('plugins_api', array( $this, 'info' ), 20, 3 );
            }

            public function update($update, $plugin_data, $plugin_file, $locales) {
                $remote = wp_remote_get($this->api_url);
                if(!is_wp_error( $remote )) {
                   $remote = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $remote ) );
                }
                return $remote;
            }

            public function info($res, $action, $args){
                if('plugin_information' === $action && $args->slug == $this->plugin_slug) {
                    $remote = wp_remote_get($this->api_url);
                            if(!is_wp_error( $remote )) {
                                    $res = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $remote ) );
                            $res->sections = json_decode(json_encode($res->sections), true);
                            }   
                }
                return $res;
            }
        }
    }

sample.json
    {
        "slug" : "simple-wp-plugin-update",
        "version" : "2.0",
        "url": "https://mydomain.com",
        "tested" : "5.8",
        "requires_php" : "5.3",
        "name" : "Sample Plugin Name",
        "author" : "<a href='https://mydomain.com'>Name</a>",
        "requires" : "3.0",
        "last_updated" : "2023-05-20 16:00:00",
        "sections" : {
            "description" : "Description for the Description tab in the modal",
            "installation" : "Description for the Install tab in the modal",
            "changelog" : "<h4>2.0</h4><ul><li>Bug fix</li></ul>"
        }
    }


try to add "package" => "https://url to the new version plugin.zip", on the filter update_plugins_.... this filter is called every time you refresh the admin page "Dashboard" -> "updates".
