Wordpress plugin update View version remove Update now
I would like to remove "Update now" below plugin name.
This is my Update info:
{
"slug" : "simple-wp-plugin-update",
"version" : "2.5",
"url": "https://my-website.com",
"package": "foo",
"tested" : "5.8",
"requires_php" : "5.3",
"name" : "Sample Plugin Name",
"author" : "<a href='https://my-website.com'>Name</a>",
"requires" : "3.0",
"last_updated" : "2023-05-20 16:00:00",
"sections" : {
    "description" : "Description for the Description tab in the modal",
    "installation" : "Description for the Install tab in the modal",
    "changelog" : "<h4>2.0</h4><ul><li>Bug fix</li></ul>"
}
}

Php which gets update info:
add_filter('update_plugins_my-domain', 'check_update', 10, 4);
    
function check_update($update, $plugin_data, $plugin_file, $locales) {
    $remote = wp_remote_get(api_url);
    if(!is_wp_error( $remote )) {
        $remote = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $remote ) );
    }
    return $remote;
}

This is showing me:
There is a new version of Sample Plugin Name available. View version 2.5 details or update now. 

If I add this:
add_action( 'in_plugin_update_message-simple-wp-plugin-update/simple-wp-plugin-update.php', 'display_update_message', 10, 2 );

function display_update_message( $plugin_info_array, $plugin_info_object ) {
    
    echo ' Some text here.';
    
}

It shows this text after the "Update now":
In following tutorial they remove "Update now" but leave "View version text..."
https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/check-license-key-in-plugin-updates.html
How can I achieve this?  They use "site_transient_update_plugins", but I use add_filter('update_plugins...
I tried this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27074740/1009466 but this completely removes everything (View version and Update now)
add_filter('site_transient_update_plugins', 'remove_update_notification');
function remove_update_notification($value) {
    unset($value->response[ plugin_basename(__FILE__) ]);
    return $value;
} 


site_transient_update_plugins is a much older workaround from before the official API was introduced, though can you add a screenshot as what you're talking about could be referring to multiple things in multiple places? Likewise can you add some context for why you are trying to do this? And where/how did you get the output of "This is my Update info:" from? If you're trying to prevent your plugin updating and getting overwritten because it has the same name as a plugin from .org then there are other better ways to fix that than hiding the update prompts

and can you add in the full code of "Php which gets update info:"? It's incomplete and missing a huge amount of information

This is a sample from here:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/426835/update-plugins-hostname-filter-show-available-updates  I want to implement license into plugin update. All works but I want to remove "Update now", leave the rest (Version info etc..)

the version info that the plugin API returns is the version info for the update, the version info for what is currently installed comes from the plugins main header in the primary PHP file, if you return any data from this update API then you are telling WordPress that an update is available. As for the handling of that update, you can always send the user to somewhere such as a license purchase etc, eitherway even if you remove the update now link that does not prevent updating, especially since WP CLI/REST/Host management tools can bypass that

what I suspect is that you want to remove the update link because you only want it to show when license data has been entered, but you still want to tell the user an update is available, is this correct? Your question is hyperfocused on a specific solution to your problem without explaining the problem itself, a classic X Y problem mistake
